# Terraform - create more VMs from a map

Tags: terraform, vmware

I have a variable file with a map:

```
 variable "machines" {
 default = {
 //  type = map(string)
 "VM1" = {
    "name" = "VM_1"
    "ip" = "192.168.10.10"
    "procs" = 8
    "ram" = 8192
    "network" = "VM_Network_A33"
    "gateway" = "192.168.10.254"
    "template" = "Templates/Template1"
    "guest_id" = "centosGuest"
 }

 "VM2" = {
      "name" = "VM_2"
      "ip" = "192.168.11.10"
      "procs" = 4
      "ram" = 4096
      "network" = "VM_Network_A34"
      "gateway" = "192.168.11.254"
      "template" = "Templates/Template2"
      "guest_id" = "centosGuest"
    }
  }
}
```

and a resource file

```
data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
  name          = var.vsphere_vm_template
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
} 
data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  name          = var.network
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "machine" {
  for_each          = var.machines
  name              = "${var.site}${var.env}${each.value.name}"
  resource_pool_id  = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id      = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
  folder            = var.vm_folder

  num_cpus          = each.value.procs
  memory            = each.value.ram
  guest_id          = each.value.guest_id

  disk {
    label            = "${var.site}${var.env}${each.value.name}.vmdk"
    size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks[0].size
    thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks[0].thin_provisioned
  }
  scsi_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type
  network_interface {
    network_id   = data.vsphere_network.network.id
    adapter_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]
  }

  clone {
    template_uuid = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id

    customize {
      linux_options {
        host_name = "${var.site}${var.env}${each.value.name}"
        domain    = "${var.site}.${var.domain}"
      }

      network_interface {
        ipv4_address = each.value.ip
        ipv4_netmask = var.network_netmask
      }

      ipv4_gateway    = var.gateway
      dns_server_list = var.network_dns
      dns_suffix_list = [var.domain]
    }
  }

}
```

I need to create as many VMs as I have in the `machines` variable, but using a single resource file. At this point, it doesn't work, as the template and network used by each machine are different.

I have a solution, but that implies having a resource file (defining `data` for template and network, and under `data` having the resources. That duplicates the resource a lot of times (I have at least 20 machines to build).

The solution I'm looking for is to have a single resource file where I can iterate thru a list of templates and a list of networks and using the same `resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "machine"` to create a VM for each entry in `machines`.

Thank you.

Edit:

vars file:

```
variable "machines" {
//  type = map(string)
default = {
  "VM1" = {
    "name" = "VM_01"
    "ip" = "192.168.10.10"
    "procs" = 8
    "ram" = 8192
    "network" = "VM_Network_A10"
    "gateway" = "192.168.10.254"
    "template" = "Templates/Template1"
    "guest_id" = "centos64Guest"
    "annotation" = "VM_1"
  }
  "VM2" = {
    "name" = "VM_02"
    "ip" = "192.168.10.11"
    "procs" = 4
    "ram" = 4096
    "network" = "VM_Network_A10"
    "gateway" = "192.168.10.254"
    "template" = "Templates/Template1"
    "guest_id" = "centos64Guest"
    "annotation" = "VM_2"
  }
  "VM3" = {
    "name" = "VM_03"
    "ip" = "192.168.11.10"
    "procs" = 1
    "ram" = 4096
    "network" = "VM_Network_A11"
    "gateway" = "192.168.11.254"
    "template" = "Templates/Template2"
    "guest_id" = "rhel4Guest"
    "annotation" = "VM_3"
  }
```

main.yml:

```
data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
  for_each      = var.machines
  name          = each.value.template
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}
data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  for_each      = var.machines
  name          = each.value.network
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "machine" {
  for_each          = var.machines
  name              = "${var.site}${var.env}${each.value.name}"
  resource_pool_id  = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id      = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
  folder            = var.vm_folder

  num_cpus          = each.value.procs
  memory            = each.value.ram
  guest_id          = each.value.guest_id
  annotation        = each.value.annotation

  //  disk {
  //    label            = "${var.site}${var.env}${each.value.name}.vmdk"
  //    size             = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].disks[0].size
  //    thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].disks[0].thin_provisioned
  //  }

  dynamic "disk" {
    for_each = [for s in data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].disks: {
    label =  index(data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].disks, s)
    //      unit_number =  index(data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].disks, s)
    size = s.size
    thin_provisioned = contains(keys(s),"thin_provisioned") ? s.thin_provisioned : "true"
    }]
    content {
      label = disk.value.label
      //      unit_number = disk.value.unit_number
      size = disk.value.size
      //      datastore_id = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"
      thin_provisioned = disk.value.thin_provisioned
    }
  }

  //  scsi_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].scsi_type
  network_interface {
  network_id   = data.vsphere_network.network[each.key].id
  adapter_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].network_interface_types[0]
  }

  clone {
    template_uuid = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].id

    customize {
      linux_options {
      host_name = "${var.site}${var.env}${each.value.name}"
      domain    = var.domain
     }

     network_interface {
       ipv4_address = each.value.ip
       ipv4_netmask = var.network_netmask
     }

     ipv4_gateway    = var.app_gateway
     dns_server_list = var.network_dns
     dns_suffix_list = [var.domain]
   }
 }
```

}

This above works, but there's still a problem, the error I get is this:

```
Error: disk: duplicate SCSI unit_number 0
```

Any idea how can I fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Comment 1/2...
Will the diff values of var.vsphere_vm_template and var.network the ones mentioned in the map variable as network and template ?

If yes, then you should for_each loop both the datasources :
data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template"  ...  with name = each.value.template
data "vsphere_network" "network"  ...  with name = each.value.network

Comment: Comment 2/2...
and when you do that, i am guessing you will be able to reference the diff network and template like this.
data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].id
data.vsphere_network.network[each.key].id

I wish i had a VM setup with me to test this to tell for sure, but i am guessing it should work. Give it a try and check if the tf plan comes up as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED!
I had to uncomment the `unit_number` because for the first disk `unit_number` is defaulted to 0, but the next ones needs to have it explicitly.

```
dynamic "disk" {
  for_each = [for s in data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].disks: {
  label =  index(data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].disks, s
  unit_number =  index(data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template[each.key].disks, s)
  size = s.size
  thin_provisioned = contains(keys(s),"thin_provisioned") ? s.thin_provisioned : "true"
}]
content {
  label = disk.value.label
  unit_number = disk.value.unit_number
  size = disk.value.size
  //      datastore_id = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"
  thin_provisioned = disk.value.thin_provisioned
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the final solution.